# Object Reference Not set to an instance of an object- Am getting this error

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Team Leader">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="gvuser_teamleader" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TeamLeaderID")  %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtuserteamleader" runat="server" Width="100px" Text='<%# Eval("TeamLeaderID") %>' CssClass="textboxstyle roundedcorner aligncenter gradientskyblue"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ListBox ID="listboxuserteamleader" runat="server" Width="110px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="listboxuserteamleader_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="textboxstyle roundedcorner aligncenter gradientskyblue"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:DropDownExtender ID="DropDownExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtuserteamleader" DropDownControlID="listboxuserteamleader"></asp:DropDownExtender>                                    
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When I am trying to fire the selected listbox index changed event and trying to bind the listbox selected value to textbox am getting this error. Also both controls are inside the gridview edit item template field.

My code:

```
protected void listboxuserteamleader_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvusers.Rows)
        {
            TextBox txtuserteamleader = (TextBox)gvusers.FindControl("txtuserteamleader");
            ListBox listboxuserteamleader = (ListBox)gvusers.FindControl("listboxuserteamleader");
            txtuserteamleader.Text = listboxuserteamleader.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try the below code:

```
protected void listboxuserteamleader_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvusers.Rows)
{
    TextBox txtuserteamleader = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtuserteamleader");
    ListBox listboxuserteamleader = (ListBox)gvr.FindControl("listboxuserteamleader");
    if(txtuserteamleader !=null && listboxuserteamleader !=null)
     {
       txtuserteamleader.Text = listboxuserteamleader.SelectedValue.ToString();
     }
 }
}
```

**Actually what was you problem :** you have created instance of gridview "gvusers" as gvr for each row... so in foreach you must have to use that instance not the "gvusers" ... here you were making mistake...

That's all

Comment: lol this might prevent the error, but it won't fix his problem.

Comment: @icemanind please be careful while reading the answer.... the actual problem in his code. he was find the row from the actual grid as you can see in his code he is using foreach 


foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvusers.Rows)

from here he must has to use grv on the place of "gvusers".. 

that i have done in my answer.....

Comment: @raman -- Sorry, you are correct. At first glance, it looked like all you did was surround the code in a null check. After looking at it more closely, I see what you did.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead sorry simon i will take care of it in future... and thanks you have pointed out for betterment

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:

protected void listboxuserteamleader_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvusers.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txtuserteamleader = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtuserteamleader");
        ListBox listboxuserteamleader = (ListBox)gvr.FindControl("listboxuserteamleader");
        txtuserteamleader.Text = listboxuserteamleader.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

When you iterate through the rows of the GridView, you have to search for the control inside that row, so the error you made is that you were searching it in the entire GridView, where each row would have this control. So you need to search it in a row.

Comment: Would you care to explain this to the OP please. Don't just dump some code here.

Comment: @user2918543 don't forgot to accept the answer helped you... to resolve the problem..

Comment: @user2918543, :) because i didn't explain it just wrote the code. no problem cheers ! now i edited it with explanation